# express js can't get param with router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got { id: e } when I do

```
router.get('/api/admin/profile?:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
});
```

this is my front end code, I'm using fetch.

```
fetch(`/api/admin/profile?id=${id}`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'GET'
    })
```

What's wrong? I'm not sure which side is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `req.query`

```
let id = req.query.id;
```

Your route is malformed, if you want to use the `:param` syntax

The route should be `'/api/admin/profile/:id'`

And then perform the request to: `'/api/admin/profile/${id}'`

```
//Using req.params
router.get('/api/admin/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params); 
    // { id: 5 } from /api/admin/profile/5
    // { id: 70 } from /api/admin/profile/70
});

//Using req.query
router.get('/api/admin/profile', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query); 
    // { id: 5 } from /api/admin/profile?id=5
    // { id: 70 } from /api/admin/profile?id=70
});
```